# Descontar un pago a una deuda total C# MySQL

Tags: mysql, c#

Tengo una tabla llamada **inmuebles** con los campos `idinmueble`, `nropartida`, `deuda`, y otra llamada **pagos** con los campos `idpago` , `fechapago`, `nropartida` y `monto`.
Mi problema es que a la hora de llenar el textbox de monto y darle a un botón que se llama registrar pago. Necesito que una consulta tome el valor de `inmuebles.deuda`, le reste el `pagos.monto` ingresado en el textbox actualice `inmuebles.deuda` con la resta realizada y cree un nuevo pago con los datos fechapago, nropartida y monto ingresados. es posible hacer todo esto en una sola consulta? o como haria para hacer todo eso solo pulsando registrar pago?

Answer (score 0):

Primero de todo bienvenido al foro.

Realmente necesitas ejecutar 2 sentencias, una para actualizar la tabla inmuebles y otra para insertar el pago en la tabla pagos.

Hay varias formas de hacerlo con una sola sentencia pero si estás aprendiendo pueden no ser obvias y a continuación te dejo algunas.

**1** Crear un [trigger](https://codigofacilito.com/articulos/triggers_mysql) que al insertar en la tabla `pagos` realize el ajuste de la deuda correspondiente.

**2** Crear un [Stored procedure](https://blog.mdcloud.es/procedimientos-almacenados-mysql-que-son-como-crearlos-y-ventajas/) para llamarlo y que realize las dos acciones pero con una simple llamada.

Existen algunas opciones más pero a mi parecer pueden ser más complicadas.